# How to implement testing on a project using java dynamic web project, and Angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, testing

I'm new to angularjs and I want to implement testing into the project.

Currently my app:

**Backend**: Java as a REST API

**Frontend**: Angularjs consuming the api.

My project runs on a tomcat server, and most of the testing frameworks for angularjs is on node.js. Is there a way for me to test the angularjs with the current setup? I don't want to install node.js, as it get more complicated for me.

Here is my project structure:

[image]

Comment: do you mean unit test?. if that you can do it with jasmine. for end to end can use protactor.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco yes, unit test. how do i integrate that into my project without installing node.js

Comment: you cant, jasmine and protactor depends on nodejs. may can use 3dparty software for end to end, like hp  https://saas.hpe.com/en-us/software/functional-testing-software-testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement Jasmine standalone testing, you do not need nodejs. However to execute the tests, we need to refresh the page constantly, i'm currently looking for a way to automate that.

**test.html**

```
<html>
        <head>
           <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
           <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="test/jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine_favicon.png">
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test/jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.css">

            <script type="text/javascript" src="test/jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="test/jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/jasmine-html.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="test/jasmine/lib/jasmine-2.6.4/boot.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular-mocks.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>  

            <!-- Angular Code -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

            <!-- Unit Testing Code -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="test/test.js"></script>
        </head>
    </html>
```

In test.js, a sample test case.

```
describe('Test', function (){
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    var $controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$httpBackend_){
          $controller = _$controller_;
          $httpBackend =_$httpBackend_;
          $scope = {};
    }));

    /*makeURLParameters*/
    it('Testing [fController]: :  makeURLParameters 1, default', function(){
        var controller = $controller('fController', { $scope: $scope });

        expect($scope.makeURLParameters()).toEqual("?page=0&size=15&sort=code&order=asc");
    });
});
```

Then in a browser, open the test.html file and it will run the test cases.

[image]